# при замене значений в базе данных сохранения не происходит и выдает ошибку?

Tags: php, laravel

***Controller***

```
 public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user= User::find($request->id);
        $user_role= User_roles::find($request->user_id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;
        $user->patronymic = $request->patronymic;
        $user->number = $request->number;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->iin = $request->iin;
        $user->groupinvalid = $request->groupinvalid;
        $user->rank = $request->rank;
        $user->save();

        if($request->rank =='админ')
        {
            $user_role = $request->role_id=1;
        }else if ($request->rank =='оператор')
        {
            $user_role = $request->role_id=3;
        }else if ($request->rank =='пользователь')
        {
            $user_role=$request->role_id=2;
        };
        $user_role->save();
        return redirect('users');

    }
```

> нужно, когда администратор изменил   ($user - >rank = $request ->rank;),
>    чтобы после начала теста если он указал какое то значение (админ, пользователь, оператор) были записаны изменения в таблице
>   user_role в столбце role_id в зависимость от рейтингов.Я это
>   сделал, но при сохранении выходит
>
> (Call to a member function save() on integer)

***model(User_role.php)***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User_roles extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'user_role';

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role','id','role_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$user_role = $request->role_id = 2;
```

Этой конструкцией вы перезаписали переменную `$user_role` теперь она не объект `User_roles` а число `2`.

В ошибке явно указано

> (Call to a member function save() on integer)

тоесть

> Невозможно вызвать метод save() у числа

Насколько я понял логику надо переписать например

```
$user_role->role_id = $request->role_id;
$user_role->save()
```

UPD:

> Creating default object from empty value

тоесть

> Создание объекта по умолчанию из пустого значения

`$user_role` пуста. Почему?

1) В процессе была перезаписана на пустое значение

2) `User_roles::find` вернула пустой результат потому что не нашла в таблице записи с таким идентификатором

Comment: мне нужно чтобы менялось число в role_id на то на которое укажу

Comment: ну тогда if(request->role_id == '1') $user_role->role_id = '???';

Comment: опять ошибка Creating default object from empty value

Comment: А ошибка потому что $user_role пуст, он не найден в базе данных под таким ИД. Вместо User_roles::find попробуйте User_roles::findOrFail и вы получите 404 ошибку

Comment: Не понимаю почему кто то проголосовал в низ, там просто присвоение числу идет, ясен пень не будет работать

Comment: @Arendach как не найдет он есть в таблице user  и его айди совпадает

Comment: @poznovashka учитесь дебажить код. Получили данные из базы - проверьте, что они валидные. Сделайте `dump($user_role);` после получения, и увидите, нужный обьект там или еще что

Answer (score 2):

Метод `save()` выполняет обновление/добавление **объекта** в базе данных. В вашем случае вы переопределяете объект `$user_role` ниже в проверке `if`:

```
      if($request->rank =='админ')
    {
        $user_role = $request->role_id=1;
    }else if ($request->rank =='оператор')
    {
        $user_role = $request->role_id=3;
    }else if ($request->rank =='пользователь')
    {
        $user_role=$request->role_id=2;
    };
```

И он внезапно становиться типа integer.
Вам же необходимо обновлять не весь объект, а всего лишь его поле.

Как решение вы можете распечатать через `print_r($user_role);` и посмотреть, какое поле нужно обновить. Для простоты вы можете использовать `find()->asArray`, а потом `print_r($user_role);` и сразу увидите конкретное поле.

Я предполагаю, что будет что-то следующее (если поле в БД называется role_id - исходя из модели):

```
    if($request->rank =='админ')
    {
        $user_role->role_id=1;
    }else if ($request->rank =='оператор')
    {
        $user_role->role_id=3;
    }else if ($request->rank =='пользователь')
    {
        $user_role->role_id=2;
    };
    $user_role->save(false); //false попробуйте для обхода валидации. Потом можно убрать, если что
```

**UDP**:
Немного непонятно, зачем вы используете конструкцию 
`$user_role = $request->role_id=1;`
Вам нужно явно присвоить role_id:
`$user_role->role_id = 1;`

**UDP2**
Старайтесь **всегда** проверять наличие переменных. Например, вот здесь:
`$user_role= User_roles::find($request->user_id);` $user_role может быть вполне не найден, и тогда в блоке проверки будет ошибка. Я бы сделал что-то типа этого:

```
if (isset($user_role) && !empty($user_role))
{
  switch ($request->rank) {
      case 'админ':
          $user_role->role_id = 1;
          break;
      case 'пользователь':
          $user_role->role_id = 3;
          break;
          //.... так далее
  }
  $user_role->save();
}
else
{
  Excp...
}
```

Comment: поругался Creating default object from empty value   строчка а которую поругался $user_role->user_role = $request->role_id=1;

Comment: @poznovashka, изменил ответ. Посмотрите

Comment: ошибки не выходит ну в role_id  у этого пользователя не произошло изменений может я не правильно указал чтобы имено этому пользователю были введены изменения

Comment: @poznovashka, вполне вероятно, что у вас $user= User::find($request->id); не находит нужного пользователя. Попробуйте дебажить

Comment: нет $user= User::find($request->id); находит того пользователя может код незнает кому кинуть изменения role_id??

Comment: Проверьте так же $request->rank, какое значение там приходит, и еще $request->user_id

Comment: значение rank  меняется в бд но не меняется значение таблицы user_role  колонки role_id  этого пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Полное решение:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user= User::find($request->id);
        $user_role= User_roles::find($request->user_id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;
        $user->patronymic = $request->patronymic;
        $user->number = $request->number;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->iin = $request->iin;
        $user->groupinvalid = $request->groupinvalid;
        $user->rank = $request->rank;
        $user->save();

        // ЗДЕСЬ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ВАШЕ НАЗВАНИЕ ПОЛЯ
        $user_role->role_id = $this->getRoleIdByRank($request->rank);

        $user_role->save();
        return redirect('users');

    }

public function getRoleIdByRank(string $rank): int
{
    $roles = [
            'админ' => 1,
            'пользователь' => 2,
            'оператор' => 3
        ];

    return $roles[$rank];
}
```

Comment: нет не работает все равно ошибки нет но в таблицу users_role  в колонке role_id  не меняется

Comment: $user->rank = $request->rank;
$user->save();
if($request->rank =='админ')

Comment: сохранение пользователя и так уже вызывается, ему надо вызвать сохранение таблицы ролей

Comment: @poznovashka так вы и не записываете роль к моделе юзера, должно быть что-то вроде такого `$user->role_id = $roles[$request->rank];` и затем `$user->save()`

Comment: @poznovashka Добавил решение

Comment: ругается App\Http\Controllers\UseCon::getRoleIdByRank() must be of the type array, integer returned

Comment: @poznovashka да, мой косяк, исправил

Comment: опять ругается Creating default object from empty value

Comment: @poznovashka потому что `user_role`  у вас равняется null